# How do I merge (as imputation) two dataset and select value from first dataset as first choice

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

Here's my first dataset. My first dataset contains rows and columns like this below. Some values in the second column (Score_d1) some are missing.

```
Customer_id   column1   column2   column3   column4
1             56        45                  64
2             45        14        45        
3             46        32        45
```

Here's my second dataset, I will using to impute my first dataset

```
Customer_id   column3   column4
1                       64
2             42        45        
3             45        73
```

If both dataset are not missing on certain value, the selected value is on the first dataset, Here's my expected output.

```
Customer_id   column1   column2   column3      column4
    1             56        45                  64
    2             45        14        45        45       
    3             46        32        45        73
```

Comment: I think you'll need `df1.combine_first(df2)` or `df2.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: Ok, the fiction I want is `combine_first`

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Do you need combine only 2 or more DataFrames?

Comment: More than 2 actually, but let me check the answer first